# Base64 encode HTTP_AUTHORIZATION headers DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a test using the Django Rest Framework:

```
self.api = APIClient()
self.api.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='client_id ' + str(self.client_id) + ' client_secret ' + str(self.client_secret))
response = self.api.post(url, payload)
```

But I get this error with the above:

> Invalid basic header. Credentials not correctly base64 encoded.

Do I need to base64 encode the header? I assumed this is done for you?
testing the same thing with curl works with no issues i.e.

```
curl -X POST -d "stuff=stuff" http://RqePZpAwyyVqal9D:18288GHFRb@127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/
```

Comment: What authentication method are you using? This looks like OAuth, but you never specify it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You do, in fact, need to base64 encode the auth strings yourself. In this case, I believe it should look something like:

```
import base64

auth = 'client_id %s client_secret %s' % (base64.b64encode(self.client_id),
                                          base64.b64encode(self.client_secret))
self.api.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=auth)
```

Comment: So does this mean curl does this for you as I don't see the same error when using it? It would be helpful if DRF added this to the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Answer (score 1):

You never specify what type of authentication method you are using, so for now I'll assume you are using some form of OAuth (because of the `client_id` and `client_secret`).

When sending the OAuth credentials [using the `Authorization` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1), you must send them as [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) credentials. So that means they should be sent in the form of `client_id:client_secret` and base64 encoded before they are sent.

```
import base64

credentials = '%s:%s' % (self.client_id, self.client_secret)
authorization = 'Basic %s' % (base64.b64encode(credentials), )

self.api = APIClient()
self.api.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=authorization)

response = self.api.post(url, payload)
```